# Can I run every ContentResult in a Controller through a universal try/catch elegantly?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, asp.net-mvc-3, controller, global-asax

I am assuming there is an elegant way to do this, but I do not know what it is.  In an application I am working on, I have a lot of ContentResults that return xml.  Every action that does return xml runs through the exact same try/catch block and I am repeating myself over and over again - here is an example of what I am talking about:

```
public ContentResult SomeAction()
{
    try
    {
        //some stuff here
    }
    catch(Exception ex) 
    { 
        HandleErrorMethod(ex);
    }
    return this.Content(someObject.ToXmlString(), contentReturnType);
}
```

This happens 3-4 times in a controller so I figure there is a way I can either paint it with an attribute, or run some sort of method in the global.asax or something like that to prevent repeating myself over and over - not to mention code changes in the future. I really have no idea where to look (I suppose that is why I am asking); Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a new **ActionFilterAttribute** and painting the necessary actions with it:

```
public class XmlExceptionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Exception == null) return;

        var response = filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = "text/xml";
        response.Write((new Status(filterContext.Exception)).ToXmlString());
    }
}
```

Then if I need it on a class, I no longer have to deal with any exception handling, it is handled:

```
[HttpGet]
[XmlException]
public ContentResult Logout(string sessionIdStr)
{
    // do stuff
    // throw exceptions if I need to, they will be handled
    return this.Content(status.ToXmlString(), contentReturnType);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have had this problem. I override the [Controller.OnException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onexception%28VS.100%29.aspx) method to handle it my own way, thus including logging and either redirecting the user to an error page or displaying a JavaScrpt error depending on the request.

You can use the HandleError attribute to get this working on the actions that need it.

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{

if (filterContext == null)
        return;

var ex = filterContext.Exception; //Your exception
//Now put the rest of your code that is currently in your handle error method. 
}

[HandleError]
public ContentResult SomeAction()
{
   //some stuff here
   return this.Content(someObject.ToXmlString(), contentReturnType);
}
```

Comment: do you place this override in each controller, or in one central place?

Comment: The problem I am having with this is that I want the Exception entered into some xml, which I will then return as the ContentResult - I am not sure how to do this int he override.

Comment: Actually have it on a base controller from which other inherit.